# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
import os
import xml.dom.minidom

li =[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/users/fedyunin_es/desktop/defaultVars"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".substvar"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(path)
            li.append(path)

for element in li:

    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(element)
    data ={}

    for info in doc.getElementsByTagName("globalVariable"):
        name = str(info.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.data)
        value = str(info.getElementsByTagName("value")[0].firstChild.data)
        data[name]=value
    print(element,"\n",data,"\n")
```

И он выпадает в ошибку:

```
line 19, in <module>
    value = str(info.getElementsByTagName("value")[0].firstChild.data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Вопрос - в чем причина? 
Первый цикл записывает в переменную **li** список директорий, в которых хранятся файлы defaultVars.substvar.

Comment: Как минимум в одном из файлов первый элемент `name` как минимум одного элемента `globalVariable` не имеет дочерних элементов.

Comment: @Hivemaster можно ли добавить игнорирование подобных моментов?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
for info in doc.getElementsByTagName("globalVariable"):
    name_tag = info.getElementsByTagName("name")
    if len(name_tag) and name_tag[0].firstChild is not None:
        name = str(name_tag[0].firstChild.data)
        value_tag = info.getElementsByTagName("value")
        if len(value_tag) and value_tag[0].firstChild is not None:
            data[name] = str(value_tag[0].firstChild.data)
```

Comment: не работает, все равно :)

Comment: @Евгений точно такую же ошибку выдаёт?